# Python array deleting items

Tags: python, list

I have array

```
a=['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '151 ihi Chun', '151 ihi Chun', '149 st Hg', '149 st Hg', '125 Tatane', '125 Tatane', '174 Sunnygat', '174 Sunnygat', '174 Sunnygat', '126 Nank', '126 Nank', '162 Rass', '162 Rass']
```

I want to remove all `''` objects, but cant.

```
a.remove('')
```

or `while a.index(''): a.remove('')`

Are don't help..

Comment: For the record, in python that is called a list, not an array. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`filter()` call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with `None` as the filter (tests for truth, so non-emptyness):

```
a = filter(None, a)
```

or a list comprehension:

```
a = [e for e in a if e]
```

If you need to explicitly allow other 'false' values and *only* want to filter out empty strings, use:

```
a = [e for e in a if e != '']
```

Answer (score 0):

If those items are actually `''`, in other words, empty strings, then you can use the following:

```
a = [x for x in a if x]
```

Since an empty string evaluates to false when used in a truth testing statement.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
for i in a:
   a.remove('')
   a.remove('')
```

i am also not sure why in first time it's not removing all but in second time sure it removes all the blank